# Nested divs when hovering the last child it hovers also the parent

Tags: html, css

I am facing this problem I have this code:

```css
article .node-inside>div:hover >label{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
  
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <label for="">text  </label>
      <article>
      
        <div class="node-inside">
          <div>
            <input type="text" />
            <label for="">text  </label>
            
            <article>
              <div class="node-inside">
                <div>
                <input type="text" />
                <label for="">text   </label>
                
                  <article>

                  </article>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
       </article>
    </div>
    
  </section>
</div>
```

This is my code that codes nesting deeper depending on how many levels I have, and I cannot put different classes on levels because it is dynamic, I need to be able when i hover the last div the label to be bordered only that not the parent. Is this possible..? how can I do this please help!!

Comment: How much sense is nesting `article` elements supposed to make in the first place, I wonder …

Comment: Hovering an element _always_ means hovering _all_ ancestors at the same time (similar to bubbling of a mouseover event in JS), there is nothing you can do about that. You need to find another structure, or another approach.

Comment: I'm mostly worrying about the empty `for=""` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the style when you hover the label or the input before its label

```css
.node-inside input:hover + label, 
.node-inside label:hover{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
  
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <label for="">text  </label>
      <article>
      
        <div class="node-inside">
          <div>
            <input type="text" />
            <label for="">text  </label>
            
            <article>
              <div class="node-inside">
                <div>
                <input type="text" />
                <label for="">text   </label>
                
                  <article>

                  </article>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
       </article>
    </div>
    
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want on div:hover you should avoid nesting div

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can't work, because the user is actually hovering over the second level div, and there is no way in CSS to say "hover over some div, but not a specific part of it".
So how about if you don't hover any div, but only the inputs and the labels? Will that work for you?

```css
article > .node-inside > div > input:hover + label,
article > .node-inside > div > input + label:hover {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
  
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <label for="">text outer </label>
      <article>
      
        <div class="node-inside">
          <div>
            <input type="text" />
            <label for="">text level 2  </label>
            
            <article>
              <div class="node-inside">
                <div>
                <input type="text" />
                <label for="">text level 3  </label>
                
                  <article>

                  </article>
                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
       </article>
    </div>
    
  </section>
</div>
```